# Van der Waal's gas satisfies $U = \int_{0}^T C_VdT - a/V + K$ (constant)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I need to show that a Van der Waal's gas satisifes 
$$U = \int_{0}^T C_VdT - \frac{a}{V} + K$$

where $K$ is constant.

The equation of state of a VDW gas is

$$\bigg(p + \frac{a}{V^2}\bigg)(V - b) = RT$$

How do I show this?   I know

$$dU = C_VdT + \bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg)_T dV$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. The first Law of Thermodynamics tells us that $dU = TdS - PdV$.
2. Write $S$ as a function of $T,V$ and take its differential.
3. Use a certain Maxwell relation.
4. Combine all this to show that
   \begin{align}
     \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T = \text{certain stuff involving only $T,V,P$}
   \end{align}
5. Invoke the equation of state and step 4 to obtain a simple expression for $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$.
6. Use the expression from 5 in tandem with the original equation for $dU$ that you wrote down, and then integrate both sides.